# How to handle "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP" exception?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium

Whenever I try to fill some non BMP character like '' as input to a text area using selenium, my chrome driver fails due to following exception:

**org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP**

The below thread says it has been fixed in google chrome, but I don't think so: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=187

I am using chrome driver (version 2.15.322448) and chrome browser (version 43.0.2357.65)

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46950897/how-to-produce-random-basic-multilingual-plane-bmp-strings-in-java to get a more generic answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=187 mentions that firefox browser has support for non-BMP characters as well.

**I tried using firefox driver and Firefox browser (version 31) and it worked. Right now this is the workaround, instead of using chrome driver to use firefox driver.**