# How to produce random Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) strings in Java?

Tags: java, string, selenium, random, apache-commons

I'm using `RandomStringGenerator` from `commons-text` 1.2-SNAPSHOT to produce random user names and passwords for tests. Using those generated strings in Selenium with Chrome driver can cause

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP
  (Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.62)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506092 (733a02544d189eeb751fe0d7ddca79a0ee28cce4),platform=Linux 4.13.0-16-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
```

Is there any way to produce [BMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) strings with existing functions already or do I have to go the obvious way to research all BMP codepoints to select randomly from them and risk to reinvent the wheel.

Not a duplicate of [How to handle "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP" exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709140/how-to-handle-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-chromedriver-only-support) since I'm interested in the solution for other purposes as well.

Comment: Is this an encoding issue?  Is one side producing UTF-16 while the other side is expecting UTF-8 (or vice versa)?

Comment: @rossum I don't have the knowledge to figure this out. I added a link to the BMP wikipedia article. Can you? I'd appreciate it.

Comment: This might be an encoding issue. Are you explicitly encoding the strings as UTF-8 before passing them off?

Comment: @Bill It's not an encoding issue, it's simply a limitation of the Chromedriver only Unicode codepoints encoded with no more than two bytes in UTF-8 are supported (the characters from UCS-2).

Answer (score 0):

`RandomStringGenerator` allows you to create a generator that is filtered by a specified range and a filtering function. Below, in Kotlin, is a function I use to generate a random BMP unicode string that's compatible with Selenium's chrome driver.

If you don't care if your random string includes non-printable characters, than you can remove the `filteredBy`.

```kotlin
private val randomBMPStringGenerator: RandomStringGenerator = RandomStringGenerator.Builder().withinRange(0x0000, 0xFFFF).filteredBy(CharacterPredicate {
    c ->
    val block: UnicodeBlock = UnicodeBlock.of(c)
    !Character.isISOControl(c) && block !== UnicodeBlock.SPECIALS
}).build()

randomBMPStringGenerator.generate(wordLength)
```