# Chrome driver crashes on unsupported non-bmp characters. How to bypass this

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium chrome driver to do some automation. Sometimes I encounter different types of unicode and non-bmp characters and it crashes my chrome. I was just wondering if there is a way to deal with this? Like removing them or doing something so my chrome driver doesn't crash.

I am using chrome driver 2.45.615291

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: ChromeDriver only supports characters in the BMP
```

Comment: Use Firefox browser instead of Chrome, check out this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31709140/how-to-handle-org-openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-chromedriver-only-support)

Comment: Does this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50439197/openqa-selenium-webdriverexception-unknown-error-chromedriver-only-supports-c/53810992#53810992

Answer (score 1):

Chrome Driver won't support characters with a Unicode after FFFF and in a future chrome releases this feature will be considered to add it.

This is a chrome driver bug, please refer: [Relevant chromedriver bug report](http://crbug.com/chromedriver/2269)

You can use Firefox, IE or Edge to avoid this issue because these browser driver will support this feature.

Comment: If I switch to firefox, does that mean I have to recode all my driver related code?

Comment: Not all the code, just the initial setup like driver initialization and some startup settings for the Firefox. Instead of running the tests in the chrome, you will use Firefox. That's it! No need to change web elements and all.